# How to create set from list of tuples

Tags: python, set

I want to work out all the permutations of three dice rolls where sum is over 7.

This is still a work in progress but efforts to calculate sets don't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

count = 0 
digits = [roll for roll in range(1,7)]
digits

digits_all = [random.sample(digits, 2) for d in digits]

def dice_role(r = digits_all):
    count =0 
    digits_all_roll_1 = r
    digits_all_roll_2 = r
    digits_all_roll_3 = r
    #return digits_all_roll_1, digits_all_roll_2, digits_all_roll_3
    data = []
    for d in digits_all_roll_1:
        data.append(tuple(d))   
        for e in digits_all_roll_2:
            data.append(tuple(e))
            for f in digits_all_roll_3:
                data.append(tuple(f))
    return data

results = dice_role()
```

#### Results

```
[(3, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (5, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 5),
 (2, 1)]
)
1
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please better define “efforts to calculate sets don't work.” by updating the question.

Comment: To calculate it reliable the random creation seems being strange, instead I'd process all possible combinations systematically.

Comment: Assume your method works as expected. Your issue is to form a set of the list `data` or `results` which contains tuples, right? Please clarify your issue and research for set-creation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: What is the expected output? shouldn't you have 3 numbers in each tuple?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the problem correctly, you could do it like this:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as CWR
result = {t for t in CWR(range(1, 7), 3) if sum(t) > 7}
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{(3, 5, 6), (1, 6, 6), (2, 2, 5), (4, 4, 4), (1, 2, 5), (4, 5, 6), (3, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (3, 4, 4), (1, 4, 5), (5, 5, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 6), (1, 1, 6), (1, 5, 6), (2, 2, 4), (3, 5, 5), (4, 4, 6), (4, 5, 5), (2, 5, 6), (4, 6, 6), (6, 6, 6), (1, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5), (3, 4, 6), (3, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (3, 6, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 4), (1, 5, 5), (5, 6, 6), (2, 2, 6), (2, 5, 5), (1, 2, 6), (2, 6, 6), (4, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (1, 3, 4), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 6), (3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 6)}
```